# How to gracefully convert a Windows path to a Unix path using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, windows, unix

For example, my directory is `C:\Program Files\Git`, I want to change to `/C/Program Files/Git`, how to use JavaScript to achieve string conversion?
Provided that the original path string is not changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a windows path to posix path using node path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799385/how-can-i-convert-a-windows-path-to-posix-path-using-node-path) and there is another libraries available on the internet.

Comment: It's pretty unlikely that a simple string mapping like that would actually *work*. There's no "/C/Program Files" directory on any UNIX/Linux system I've ever seen.

Comment: `"C:\\Program Files\\Git".replace(/\\/g, "/").replace(/(.):/,"/$1")`

Comment: Uh,you change the original string,You changed \ to \\

Comment: You can't change an original string..  \\ that's escaping in JS, the real value is \

Comment: @Keith - those two `replace()` calls can be collapsed into a single regex replacement: `string.replace(/\\|^(.):/g, '/$1')`

Comment: @dbenham The reason I did two was in case you had filenames with colons in, but colons don't appear to be valid filenames, so yes, that single regex would be better.